# Isekai Manga about MC have a poisonous/cursed body

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I once read a manga about this *isekai* (?). From what I remembered, the MC was so mistreated had some kind of cursed or poisonous body, where nobody can touch him.

This dungeon or kind of gate where he is in will grant them a wish if they completed it.

I also remember that he follows a journal by this one adventurer. Whenever he reaches somewhere, this adventurer leaves his journal. The MC follows and enjoys it. There is also this Japanese girl that lives in the dungeon and is crazy strong. I remember one of the arcs where he visits a village of adventurers that can't pass to the next stage. These adventurers actually kill passing adventurers and eat them. But when they eat the MC's body parts, they all die since he has the poisonous/cursed body.

In the end, the MC finished the dungeon and becomes an assassin of some sort.

I love the dark theme behind this manga and also the ending is satisfying, at least to me.

Comment: Looks like they crossposted to https://www.reddit.com/r/manga/comments/jy8ypt/need_help_finding_isekai_manga_about_mc_that_have/

Answer (score 1):

This is *[Dungeon Seeker](https://myanimelist.net/manga/98820/Dungeon_Seeker)*

> Junpei Takeda, a high school student, is childhood friends with Noriko Tatsumiya and the bully Kido Shouta. One day, during the usual course of bullying Junpei, they were suddenly summoned to a different world by the whim of "God." Summoned Heroes with cheats, or so he thought. But it turns out Junpei's stats were even worse than an average farmer. Tricked into a deathly labyrinth by the only one he trust, he walks the journey for revenge.

The poisonous body aspect was gained in his first encounter, but not revealed until the third one.

> [image: Description of No Life King ability]
>  **No Life King** - This attribute alters body tissue. The new body tissues will produce a strong neurotoxin that courses through the whole body - be it bones, flesh, or bodily fluids